# Android's ArrayAdapter - add strings listview instead of replace

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

This is how I add an array to listview:

```
ListView my_listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, my_array);
my_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my_array is uri of a file.

It works well. But next next time I want to array a new array, then I don't want to replace with with new one instead add new ones to the existing ones. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to be using an `ArrayList<String> my_array` rather than a `String[] my_array` and then you can do:

```
my_array.addAll(other_array);
```

to add elements from a new array to your array. Then you can do:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to update your ListView with the new elements.