# How can I do an array for a listView with Strings located on parse.com?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, parse-platform

I have this strings array just with the purpose of testing a list view

```
  <string-array name="prueba">

        <item> calculo </item>
        <item> fisica </item>
        <item>logica</item>
        <item>programacion</item>
        <item> adsad</item>
        <item>asdasdasdsad</item>
        <item> trtr </item>
        <item> yuuyu </item>
        <item>ngngn</item>
        <item>dgdg</item>
        <item> liuj</item>
        <item>kmbbm</item>

    </string-array>
```

this is the listView code

```
public class Grades extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.grades_fragment,container,false);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.prueba, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }    

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {    

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"item" + position , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

So what I want is to instead of using that "test" array, using some strings that are located on my Parse.com Data, adding elements to the array when a string is added to the Data base in Parse.com

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some info on how to retrieve data from parse.com [here -> android_guide#objects](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects)
Using a ParseQuery, you can obtain the ParseObject.
You can then query this object for details and add this to your listview.

code snippets from link above.

To get the object.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

To query the object:

```
int score = gameScore.getInt("score");
String playerName = gameScore.getString("playerName");
boolean cheatMode = gameScore.getBoolean("cheatMode");
```

They have "getX" methods for all data types.

To add this to your listview.
using [arrayadapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

> void  add(T object)
>
> Adds the specified object at the end of the array.
>
> void  addAll(Collection collection)
>
> Adds the specified Collection at the end of the array.
>
> void  addAll(T... items)
>
> Adds the specified items at the end of the array.

This [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5394828/3956566) shows how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the strings from the object by the same name through which you saved. Say for example it is listStrings.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> myObject= ParseQuery.getQuery("listStrings");
```

After that just call this function

```
myObject.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
   if (e == null) {
     // Assign the values here and use it accordingly
   } else {
     // Failure!
  }
}
});
```

You can also use the following function:

```
fetchAllInBackground(List<T> objects)
```

Comment: and then, how can i make that string go to my array?

Comment: if you use fetchAllInBackground just use for loop till size of list and read required string values from each parseobject and add it to your list as myLIst.add(object.get("myvalue"));