# how can i implement a loop in XML file

Tags: android, arrays, xml, loops

`$`

```
<string name="app_name">demoMark</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="spinner_header">Group Mate</string>
<string-array name="demo_name">
    <item>Product Amount</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

`$`

`ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapteradapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.demo_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    itemAmount.setAdapter(adapter);`

[image: here is the screenshot with arrayadapter]
[image: here is the screenshot]

Is there anyway that i can implement a loop in the string array in the `String.XML` ?
it will be so helpful if anyone help me out with this.

Comment: You're going to need to use an Array Adapter like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394746/androids-arrayadapter-add-strings-listview-instead-of-replace

Comment: I already added the array adapter . I added another screenshot of that can you tell me what should I do now ?

Comment: can you add your actual code to this post?

Comment: I did now you can check that

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: @njzk2 i meant I want to add item in my string array from my java code and items will be like 1,2,3,4,5,6.....100 so i want to use a loop to add the numbers in the items in my String.xml 
so i asked if there is any way to do this ?

Comment: what would be the use of putting that in the xml file?

Comment: these will show in the spinner drop_down item .

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a loop in xml directly. Use an external script to generate your xml is an alternative way to do what you need...

Comment: Can you tell me more about the external script ??

Comment: Just code a python/bash/whatever script you will run to create your strings.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python

Comment: Actually I am using JAVA . I am not an python user. it will be so helpful if it was in java :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79551/discussion-between-muhtadi-akif-and-mederic).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's unable to do that as it does not support xsd. You can read related discussion at [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7395).

To parse XML in your way, I recommend [Simple library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) to process xml data. This library reads XML data and creates into objects (so called deserialization) for you.

The tutorial at above link will give you enough examples, but you might need to do many trial-and-error in order to reflects xml structure to object hierarchy.

Comment: is there any other way i can do it without library ?

Comment: @MuhtadiAkif // `XmlPullParser` is default android XML library but it is too naive to use.